# Sqlite in Android 4.4 is deleted when closing app

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got a problem with sqlite in my application. The problem is: My sqlite with all data is vanished after closing app, reinstalling app in eclipse studio. I close app using back-arrow on my device or swipe out icon of this app from manager bar shown on the photo. When I add new position to my listView, it works fine but When I swipe out application from manager bar it destroyes my sqlite database and I lose everything. I store my list view in global object (extends Application). Problem is with this vanishing database. What is wrong here? I'm using Android 4.4 on tablet Samsung Galaxy Tab 4.

PHOTO:

[image: My app closing with "swipe-out" gesture]

EDITED:

My DBHelper Class

```
public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "gifs";
      public static final String NAME = "name";
      public static final String RATING = "rating";
      public static final String DATE = "date";
      public static final String URL = "url";
      public static final String COVERURL = "coverurl";
      public static final String MAIN_CONTENT_URL = "mainURL";

      public static final String  DATABASE_FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/storeUGif/";


      public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "items.db";
      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + NAME + " text" + "," + RATING 
              + " int" + "," + URL + " text" + "," + DATE + " text" + "," + COVERURL + " text" + "," + MAIN_CONTENT_URL + " text" + ");";

    public SqliteHelper(Context context) {

        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //super(context,DATABASE_FILE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        if(GlobalApplicationState.DEBUG_MODE)
       System.out.println(DATABASE_FILE_PATH);

      }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

         database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(database);

    }




}
```

Insert into method:

```
public void instertItemToDataBase(GifModel model)
    {
        if(!dataBaseManager.isOpen())
        {
            dataBaseManager.open();
        }
        if(!demotywatorBaseManager.isOpen())
        {
            demotywatorBaseManager.open();
        }

        if(model.getMainLinkToTheContent().contains("http://kwejk.pl"))
        {
            dataBaseManager.insertGifToDataBase(model);

            //dataBaseManager.close();
        }
        else if(model.getMainLinkToTheContent().contains("http://demotywatory.pl"))
        {
            demotywatorBaseManager.insertGifToDataBase(model);
            //demotywatorBaseManager.close();
        }

    }
```

And the last one:

```
public void insertGifToDataBase(GifModel newGif) {

        //System.out.println(newGif.getMainLinkToTheContent());

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SqliteHelper.NAME, newGif.getNameOfIteme());
        values.put(SqliteHelper.RATING, newGif.getRating());
        values.put(SqliteHelper.URL, newGif.getUrl());
        values.put(SqliteHelper.DATE, newGif.getAddedDate());
        values.put(SqliteHelper.COVERURL, newGif.getCoverUrl());
        values.put(SqliteHelper.MAIN_CONTENT_URL, newGif.getMainLinkToTheContent());
        database.beginTransaction();
        database.insert(SqliteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        database.endTransaction();

    }
```

EDIT 2:

```
public ArrayList<GifModel> getAllGifs() {

        ArrayList<GifModel> allGifs = new ArrayList<GifModel>();

        try
        {
            Cursor cursor = database.query(SqliteHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();  // Here exception shows up.
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                GifModel gif = cursorToNewGif(cursor);
                allGifs.add(0,gif);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();


        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.getCause();
        }
//      for(int i = 0; i < allGifs.size(); i++)
//      {
//          System.out.println("CUrosr"+allGifs.get(i).toString());
//      }
        return allGifs;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is in the code you've written but didn't include in the question.

Comment: Are you sure you have properly edited the database? Don't forget to include `setTransactionSuccessful()` and `endTransaction()` calls in that order after you want to permanently save changes to the database

Comment: I can include code but tell me exactly what part should I include.

Comment: Your DbHelper class would be helpful to see

Comment: The code that you think should write to the database and how it's called.

Comment: `reinstalling app in eclipse studio` OMG! I really needed **another IDE**!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `setTransactionSuccessful()` before `endTransaction()` to actually apply the changes. Without the success flag the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: I have added this line to code. When I close app and open again listView is populated, but when I swipe my app from let's say "recent opened app" all information is erased. Why?

Comment: Possibly because there's another problem reading the data back. For example, it works with the in-memory adapter data but cannot populate an adapter from the database when the app is starting.

Comment: It could be that you're not reloading properly.  When you close the app, use adb to see if the DB file exists and what's in it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have found problem... When I restart app I got exception when cursor move to first position: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null". It happens when I close my app using swipe-out. Before system tells me that database exists.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how the SqliteHelper works, I create databases by hand. But, I think that:

**You're creating a new table on every run**. See your DATABASE_CREATE string:
Create table x(foo int, bar int);

Add the **IF NOT EXISTS** to the table creation expression. Making it:

```
CREATE TABLE x IF NOT EXISTS(foo INT, bar INT);
```

This way you'll create the table only if it doesn't exist already. 
If it exists, it won't do anything.

In your code:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "if not exists (" + NAME + " text" + "," + RATING 
          + " int" + "," + URL + " text" + "," + DATE + " text" + "," + COVERURL + " text" + "," + MAIN_CONTENT_URL + " text" + ");";
```

Comment: I've checked if data base exists in sqliteHelper and it says it exists. In my application I have a Fragment which use global list. DataBase exists but listView in Fragment is empty. What do you propose?

Comment: Modify your DATABASE_CREATE adding the IF NOT EXISTS.

Comment: I have done as you said. It works fine until I swipe out this app from "recent opened list". Then I open it again and check if database exists -> it exists but I got error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null" when cursor wants to get the first element. It happenes with this type of closing app everytime. I also turn off device and after relaunching app it happens also. If I close app with swipe out gesture from recent list in MainActivity onStop() and onDestroy() method is not called. Why?

Comment: Victor Hugo Schwaab can we talk on the chat?

Comment: Could you copy the code lines near the error? Where specifically?

Comment: I've solved the problem: In my database when I insert new position I forget to fill all columns. I've downloaded additionall app for sqlite and observe the database and it showed me that one column was missing. After adding something to it everything started working and cursor doesn't have problems now. It wasn't obvious but problem is solved.

Comment: Excellent! That's just great